# $I(X_1\cap X_2)=\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X_1, X_2\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ are algebraic sets. Why does $I(X_1\cap X_2)=\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$?

In particular, why do we have the inclusion $I(X_1\cap X_2)\subset\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have$$I(X_1\cap X_2)=I(V(I(X_1))\cap V(I(X_2)))=I(V(I(X_1)+I(X_2)))=\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$$
The only non-trivial equation is the last one which follows from the Nullstellensatz ($I(V(J))=\sqrt{J}$)